# How do you update the NetworkConfiguration of an Azure Cloud Service deployment while it's running

Tags: azure, acl, azure-cloud-services, web-application-firewall

How can we change the IP Restriction Rules while the Cloud Service is running. (A reboot is acceptable).
For example, add / remove an IPAddress.

We don't really want to redeploy and we definitely don't want to repackage.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/schema-cscfg-networkconfiguration

[image]

Comment: Security groups don't exist in the service. You need to go to either create a new Security Group or go to your existing Network Security Group, resources and create the rule. I already gave you the link for security groups. Did you even read it before down voting my answer?

Comment: Shame we can't use "D:\Packages\GuestAgent\GuestAgent\AppAgentRuntime.mcf"

Comment: ah ha, ok so realizing what you are asking I started doing some searching and I think I found something that might help. Mentions a couple other option that aren't covered in the article. This solution would restrict ips at the firewall itself opposed to what I proposed. Hope it helps. http://fabriccontroller.net/apply-ip-address-restrictions-to-your-windows-azure-cloud-services/ You might want to edit your question.

Comment: We are currently using the https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2013/05/07/using-windows-firewall-to-restrict-access-to-windows-azure-instances/ model but that requires the elevated permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Using Network Security Groups. This can be done at any time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/security-overview

In NSG overview add either the tag or IP range and the desired restriction or allow.

Comment: Would you need to add a Classic Azure Virtual Network? Feels a shame that CloudServices has IP Address rules but only on deploy.

Comment: No, you can only set the rules after you deploy your resources, unless you use an ARM template. There is no need to restart or stop any services though. When you deploy a resource, if you don't specify a Virtual Network it will create one by default. So just go the the resource in question, then under setting > networking. Change the rules here.

Comment: Where is this setting in cloud services?

Comment: No...You need to either create a new Security Group or go to your existing Network Security Group, resources and create the rule.